# Join condition in JPQL query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to create this query using JPA repositories:

```
SELECT * FROM api_centros c
LEFT JOIN api_centros_usuarios cu ON (c.id = cu.centro_id AND cu.usuario_id = ?)
WHERE cu.usuario_id IS NULL OR cu.paciente = 1
```

I've tried:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM CentroEntity c LEFT JOIN c.relacionUsuarios AS r ON r.centro = c AND r.usuario = :usuario WHERE r.usuario IS NULL OR r.paciente = TRUE")
```

But this throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidWithClauseException: with clause can only reference columns in the driving table [SELECT c FROM es.plexus.api.vo.CentroEntity c LEFT JOIN c.relacionUsuarios AS r ON r.centro = c AND r.usuario = :usuario WHERE r.usuario IS NULL OR r.paciente = TRUE]
```

Tried to reformat the query in antoher way but I can't figure out how. In short, I've got 3 entities. 2 of them are related by the third (join table with each id from the other entities and a true/false value). I need all the entities (table `api_centros` in the query) related with a certain user (the other table) that has that third value to true OR is not related at all (or, looking at it the other way, I need everything (related and not related) from the first entity except the ones related and with that value to false).

The entities are:

`Centro` (only need the id), `Usuario` (only need the id) and `CentroUsuario` with 3 fields: `centro_id`, `usuario_id` and `paciente` (true/false).

Any ideas? Thanks!

*Edit:
This is the UsuarioCentroEntity (relationship entity):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", nullable = false)
private UsuarioEntity usuario;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "centro_id", nullable = false)
private CentroEntity centro;

private boolean paciente;
```

Comment: show us the mapping files

Comment: What is the "ON r.centro = c" about? The join across the relation will include the relation constraint itself, so you don't put it. You only use "ON" when you have something EXTRA to add to the on clause of the join

Comment: Already tried that and It was giving the same exception: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidWithClauseException: with clause can only reference columns in the driving table [SELECT c FROM es.plexus.api.vo.CentroEntity c LEFT JOIN c.relacionUsuarios AS r ON r.usuario = :usuario WHERE r.usuario IS NULL OR r.paciente = TRUE]`